# pageUp and pageDown used to move caret

Tags: textmate2

**How to move the page together with the caret?**

In TM1 it was possible to specify this in
`~/Library/KeyBindings/DefaultKeyBindings.dict`

However [it seems not to work in TM2](http://groups.google.com/group/textmate/browse_thread/thread/70868ff9ada2f66a/1b8818cee6677f4c).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like this option is now implemented in the lastest version of textmate2 , released on 2012-02-18, version 9064, as mentioned in the release notes.

- Implement option page up/down (for moving caret).